# cypress run && node cucumber-html-report.js not generating html report when assertion fail

Tags: cucumber, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I want to generate the html report in cypress when assertion failed.

I am using "multiple-cucumber-html-reporter" and I am able to generate when all passes.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a failure `cypress run` returns a non-zero exit code and `&&` will only continue executing if the previous call ends with a successful exit code. You need to switch the `&&` to `;`.

Comment: Thank you. cypress run ; node cucumber-html-report.js- i tried this its still not working. is their any other way to generate instead of providing node cucumber-html-report.js in script package.json file. please help

Comment: What happens when you use the ; character ? Does it give you a different error than if you use &&?

Comment: With ; still it's not generating reports. As of now I tried with || seems it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using

cypress run || node cucumber-html-report.js

This works for me